# MYSQL Explain Rows_examined doesn't match

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I've got a query in mysql_slow_queries log as follows:

**Query_time: 4.642323  Lock_time: 1.821996 Rows_sent: 14  Rows_examined: 27099**

```
SET TIMESTAMP=1356068688;
SELECT gw.id website_id, gw.name,gw.url,gw.language,gw.title,gw.nickname, gd.id, 
        gd.deal_title, gd.cdeal_title, gd.deal_details, gd.cdeal_details, 
        gd.discount_price, gd.original_price, gd.savings, gd.expiry, gd.shop, 
        gd.location, gd.clocation, gd.limited_offer, gd.contact, gd.url website, 
        gd.affiliate_url, gd.tags, gd.pic_url, gd.featured, gd.top_pos, 
        gd.sub_pos, gd.appeal, gd.redeem_until, gd.noofpurchased 
FROM groupon_deals gd 
INNER JOIN groupon_websites gw ON gw.id=gd.groupon_websites_id 
WHERE gd.tags LIKE '%technology-and-gadgets%' AND gd.pubDate >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND 
        gd.hidden = 0 AND gd.pubDate < SYSDATE() AND 
        gd.id NOT IN (1,30079,30090,30116,30118,30070,30136,30137,30138,30156,30103,30157,30038,30044,30084,30025,30013,30111,30030,30020,30059,30087,30026,30016,30112,30031,30021,30005,30092,30027,30017,30113,30049,30032,30023,30006,30096,30040,30028,30018,30120,30033,30024,30008,30110,30029,30019,30128,30131,30129,30100,30004,29995,30076,30126,30069,30078,30071,30034,30080,30065,30073,30082,29987,30074,30117,30068,29981,30098,30102,30088,30119,30135,30155,30107,29997,30041,30046,30077,30003,29992,30058,30097,30014,29999,30066,30127,30009,30081,29993,30060,30015,30114,30000,29985,30099,30010,30083,29994,30061,30022,30115,30001,30072,29986,30011,30086,30062,30123,30002,30075,29990,30054,30160,30094,30012,29998,30064,30125,30039,30130,30134,29982,30159,30048,30047,30158,30043,30101,30104,30106,30122,30056,30057,30063,30161,30053,29984,30132,30109,30036,30108,30037,30121,30045,30124) AND 
        (gw.language = 'C' OR gw.language = 'B') 
ORDER BY gd.sub_pos,gd.noofpurchased DESC
```

Now when I go to phpMyAdmin and run the same query using EXPLAIN, I get the output here:
http://algaryeung.com/temp/explain-output.jpg

I have 2 questions:

1) How come the rows_examined in the log is 27099 vs the rows_examined in the EXPLAIN 37, 756 are different?  Do I need to multiple the 2 values in the EXPLAIN to get the real rows examined?

2) I know this is kind of open ended, but how would I go about improving the existing query?  I've indexed the field groupon_deals.groupon_websites_id and I assume there might be some way to improve the NOT IN part of the query.  Not expecting a complete answer here but any idea where to start digging/learning?

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL `EXPLAIN` provides an estimate, a prediction, of the number of rows that will be returned as a result of each step.

What `EXPLAIN` really gives you is the execution plan, that is the access path that will be used, the order of operations, and which indexes will be used.  It does not actually process the statement to get accurate row counts, it only predicts how many rows will be retrieved, based on information it has about the number of rows in the tables, and the cardinality and distribution of values within the columns.

According to the EXPLAIN output you provided, the query is doing a full scan of the `groupon_websites` table. For each `id` value retrieved (which is not eliminated by a predicate), MySQL is performing an index lookup, on the `groupon_websites_id` column of the `groupon_deals` table.

---

For this query, performance may be improved a bit with an index

```
... ON groupon_deals (groupon_websites_id, hidden, pubDate, id)
```

---

I think a good place to start "digging" would be to understand the `EXPLAIN` statement.

If you have some understanding about how MySQL actually goes about processing a SQL statement, which "operations" MySQL can perform, and which of those "operations" can make use of suitable indexes, that's a foundation for understanding the output from `EXPLAIN`.

I suggest starting here, in the MySQL documentation: [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, knowing that the EXPLAIN doesn't really process the statement but rather gives a plan explains a lot (no pun intended).